# How to pass an object in a dynamically created function call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a jQuery click event bind to thumbnail images of the class="thumnail":

```
$(".thumbnail").click(function(){
  var obj = new Object();
  obj.el = "imageEdit";
  obj.id = $(this).attr("id").replace("img_","");
  openDialogue(obj);
});
```

As you can see, I am:

1. making an object "obj",
2. calling a function "openDialogue",
3. passing my object "obj" to openDialogue.

openDialogue will open a dialog box, and in the dialog box I am going to do an ajax call, retrieve the image path, and populate the dialog box with the image. This works fine when the thumbnail loads on a page refresh, as a form action page, using php.

But I also need to populate the thumbnail boxes using js/jQuery, on a select field change, and I guess jQuery doesn't event listen to a dynamically created element, like a button or an anchor or an image (Am I wrong about this?).

When I change the product using the select box, I will populate the thumbnail spaces with thumbnail jpgs using this code:

```
$("#picture_row").empty();
$.each( data, function( k ) {
  var id;
  $.each( data[k], function( kk,vv ){
    if(kk == "id"){ 
      id = vv;
      var e = $('<div class="thumbBox" id="imageBox_'+id+'"></div>');
      $('#picture_row').append(e);
    }
    else if(kk == "file_name"){ 
      var obj = new Object();
      obj.el = "imageEdit";
      obj.id = id;

      var file_name = vv.replace(".jpg","_thumb.jpg");
      var img = $("<img class='thumbnail' id='img_"+id+"' src='../images/products/thumbs/"+file_name+"' onclick='openDialogue("+obj+");return false;' />");
      $("#imageBox_"+id).append(img);
    }
  })
});
```

As you can see, it is these lines where I create the new image, and try to add an onclick:

```
var img = $("<img class='thumbnail' id='img_"+id+"' src='../images/products/thumbs/"+file_name+"' onclick='openDialogue("+obj+");return false;' />");
$("#imageBox_"+id).append(img);
```

For some reason, I can't pass my object "obj" to the dynamically creation function call:

```
onclick='openDialogue("+obj+");return false;'
```

I get this error:

```
Timestamp: 9/28/2013 7:04:33 PM
Error: SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
Source File: (domain and path)/management/
Line: 1, Column: 21
Source Code:
openDialogue([object Object]);return false;
```

Comment: Tip: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Btw., yes you are wrong about jQuery not even considering dynamically created elements. It uses event bubbling to listen to events triggered on elements that don't exist at the time you're binding the handler. Using it is done so: `$('#parentElement').on('click', '#button', function( jqEvt ) { /* do something! */ });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to inline the event handling use jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
var img = $("<img class='thumbnail' id='img_"+id+"' src='../images/products/thumbs/"+file_name+"' />")
.on('click', function(){
  openDialogue(obj);
  return false;
}) ;
$("#imageBox_"+id).append(img);
```

Comment: ...and we have lift off! Green check on your answer, just as soon as SO allows me to do it. Thank you Musa. P.S.: I made a slight edit, I did a `.on('click', function(){` instead of just `on('click', function(){`